# Native iOS Rss Feed reader opening full story in safari

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rss

I have an iPhone app that uses a native Rss feed reader, and i wanted to make a button on it that would take you out of the app and bring you to the full story in safari, but i dont know how to code it. I used a tutorial to make the rss reader: cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader . All of the code that I am using is from that tutorial, except for the part about the podcast.
If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`openURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a) method to open a URL in Safari.

Comment: but the URL is different for each rss story

Comment: What's your point? Just call openURL with any URL to open it.

Comment: I'm a beginning programmer. How would I do that. can you tell me the code?

Comment: Based on looking at that tutorial, I think you can use `[item objectForKey:@"link"]` to get the link as a string. Then use `URLWithString:` to get a URL.

Comment: Is that all I should put in the IBAction?

Comment: Can you please tell me all of the code that  needs to go in the IBAction?

Comment: @sam he did. see that comment with `[item objectForKey:@"link"]` that's an NSString that you can put into `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item objectforKey:@"link"]]];` and it'll open it.

Comment: Is that all i put in my IBAction, and then link it to a button?

Comment: I tried that out in an action but it comes back with an NSInvalidArgumentException and the reason in the debugger console is:          2011-08-18 14:55:53.906 Ross Mobile[6076:207] -[__NSCFDictionary objectforKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a71720          and               
2011-08-18 14:55:53.925 Ross Mobile[6076:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectforKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a71720'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: You have to capitalize the F in `objectForKey:`. Please use a little of your own common sense instead of just blindly trying what we give you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The bug is gone but it still wont open in safari. It doesn't do anything when its pressed. And yes everything is linked up correctly.